# What is the maximum size/length of IDs, especially for comment IDs

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to find the maximum size of the different IDs of the YouTube API.

Can someone tell me where can I found this or what is the maximum number of characters of:
- Comments IDs
- Channels IDs
- Playlists IDs
- Subscriptions IDs

Thank you!
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the [`Comments`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) ID from the JSON response in the [Resource representation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#resource-representation) (`"id": string`) section of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

See the JSON structure of a `comments` resource

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#comment",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "authorDisplayName": string,
    "authorProfileImageUrl": string,
    "authorChannelUrl": string,
    "authorChannelId": {
      "value": string
    },
    "channelId": string,
    "videoId": string,
    "textDisplay": string,
    "textOriginal": string,
    "parentId": string,
    "canRate": boolean,
    "viewerRating": string,
    "likeCount": unsigned integer,
    "moderationStatus": string,
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "updatedAt": datetime
  }
}
```

Same with [`Channels`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) ID, [`Playlist`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists) ID, [`Subscription`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions) ID.

Unfortunately, coming from the YouTube developer that they do not guarantee about the length of each specific ID.

Here is a [StackExchange post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13854/are-youtube-codes-guaranteed-to-always-be-11-characters) as a reference.

It was mentioned that the word is coming from a YouTube developer, [here is the link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/oAztQ3f1tcM) from Google Groups Forum to justify.

> Hello Hans,
>
> I don't see anywhere in the documentation where we officially commit 
>   to a standard length of 11 characters for YouTube video ids. It's one 
>   of those things where we have a current implementation, and it may 
>   stay that way indefinitely. But we're not offering any official 
>   commitment to that, so proceed at your own risk.
>
> A better approach, though one that's more involved, would be to take 
>   each video id and make a request to the YouTube API to see if it's 
>   valid. E.g., make an HTTP GET to
>
> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID
>
> and see if you get back a HTTP 200 response. Of course, if you take 
>   that approach, videos that have been removed from YouTube will come 
>   back as invalid (which may or may not be what you want) and videos 
>   that have been very recently uploaded to YouTube might also come back 
>   as invalid.
>
> Cheers, 
>   -Jeff Posnick, YouTube API Team

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's what I thought, but wanted to make sure... Actually, my problem was that I gave 50 characters for comment IDs few years ago, thinking that 50^64 would be enough to store comments (I know all 50^64 combination won't be used, but even 1% of this would have been enough). I will give it 255 characters, hoping that will be sufficient, and pay attention to other IDs I also gave 50 characters. Thank you!